# Combination of Scrollview HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Most of the answer of these kind of question usually "android:fillViewPort = true", but I think it's different in my case

my xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="PROFILE PAGE"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_title"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="ss"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_titlexx"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

<TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="FB/G+   : "
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewIDLogin"
                    android:text="Column 2"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:text="Adress : "
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
                        android:text="street"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:typeface="sans"   />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:text="Contact : "
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewContact"
                        android:text="221149089xx"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDiamondPoint"
                android:text="2150"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:background="@color/material_grey_100"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:text="sum of treatment  : "
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewJumlahPerawatan"
                        android:text="8 "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:text="Diamond : "
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewdp"
                        android:text="500 "
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:text="Diamond sum         : "
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewDiamondTotal"
                        android:text="2650 "
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:typeface="sans"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewHistory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="last treatment"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```

i remember wasting my time trying to change values everywhere.. , but i still can't make the layout fill the width of the area.

i just want my textview & table layout fill all the width of the screen.

Comment: Why are you using a HorizontalScrollView if you just want that its children elements fill the whole screen?

Comment: sorry, i updated my xml, it actually contains table layout too

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `TextView` fill all the width of the screen then I don't think you required `HorizontalScrollView`. Just remove it and set width of `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` as given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="PROFILE PAGE"
            android:id="@+id/profile_title"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="ss"
            android:id="@+id/profile_titlexx"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry, i actually have more child, i just cut it because i think it would be simpler to read.  i actually need to put some textviews and some tableLayouts. but what i got was all the view only used half of the width

Comment: It might be because your `LinearLayout` width `wrap_content` change it to `match_parent` and check it.

Comment: Android Studio suggest me to use wrap content, have tried to change it anyway, but not working, ps: i updated my xml

Answer (score 0):

I got it working finally by using this structure :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                ... Child layout....
```